# Angular filter pipe for leaflet markers

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, leaflet, pipe

I have a select, called district, where all the districts of the city are listed.

The goal is when selecting a district to apply a filter which will eventually display only the leaflet markers from the relevant district on the map. Any ideas how I could achieve that?

the following code is from my map component, it shows how the data comes in and markers are created:

```
refresh() {
    this.artworkService.retrieveAll().then( (artworkList) => {
      this.artworkList = artworkList;
      for (const artwork of this.artworkList) {
        const popupOptions = { className: 'customPopup' };
        const popupInfo =
          "<span class='customPopup'><b>" +
          artwork.name +
          "</b></span>" +
          "<br/>" +
          artwork.firstname + " " + artwork.lastname +
          "<br/>" +
          artwork.streetname + artwork.streetnumber + ", " + artwork.zipcode;
        console.log(artwork.name);
        L.marker([artwork.latitude, artwork.longitude], this.markerIcon)
          .addTo(this.map)
          .bindPopup(popupInfo, popupOptions);
      }

    });

  }
```

this is my html for the filter:

```
<div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left">
  <div class="filterButton leaflet-control">
    <i class="fa fa-filter fa-7x"></i>
    <strong class="mt-4">District</strong>
    <select class="ml-1" name="zipcode" [(ngModel)]="zipcode">
      <option>-All-</option>
      <option *ngFor="let zipcode of artworkList">{{zipcode}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain more what you are trying to achieve? When you click a district you want to list the leaflet markers but where. I am new to leaflet but if your problem is related to angular I can help if you explain little more

Comment: Leaflet is based on open-street-map! Its just  a map, and on it are a lot of little pins. In this app these pins correspond to all sorts of public art one finds in the city, but one looses oversight if there are too many pins. Hence I want to have a filter where I select for example district one and it will only show the pins from that district, and remove the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it can be achieved with a pipe but I will give another implementation for your issue. A method which removes all markers and add those needed once you change the value of the select option:

template:

```
<select
  class="ml-1"
  name="zipcode"
  [(ngModel)]="zipcode"
  (ngModelChange)="changeZipcode()"
>
  <option>-All-</option>
  <option *ngFor="let list of artworkList">{{list.zipcode}}</option>
</select>
```

ts:

```
map;
artworkList;
zipcode;
popupOptions = {
  className: "test test2"
};

buildMarkers(artworkList) {
   for (let artwork of artworkList) {
       this.buildPopup(artwork);
   }
}

buildPopup(object) {
    const popupInfo = `
        ${object.name} <br/>
        ${object.firstname}
        ${object.lastname} <br/>
        ${object.streetname} ${object.streetnumber}
        , ${object.zipcode}
      `;
    L.marker([object.latitude, object.longitude], this.markerIcon)
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup(popupInfo, this.popupOptions);
}

changeZipcode() {
    // empty map of any markers
    this.map.eachLayer(layer => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Marker) this.map.removeLayer(layer);
    });
    if (this.zipcode === "-All-") {
      // build all markers like before selection
      this.buildMarkers(this.artworkList);
    } else {
      // return onject inside array which contains the specific zipcode
      const currentArtworklist = this.artworkList.filter(
        list => list.zipcode == this.zipcode
      );
      this.buildMarkers(currentArtworklist);
    }
}
```

[Full demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k51pkw53wr)